# cartopy: zoom in to a region

Tags: python, gis, cartopy

I would like to use Cartopy to plot only a region (in my case, North and South America).

I am currently using the following code:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lon, lat, freq = .., ..., ...  # initialize longitude and latitude and line width
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=.5)

for la, lo, fq in zip(lat, lon, freq):
    plt.plot(lo, la, color='red', linewidth=fq, marker='o', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Then it produces:

[image]

What I want (zoomed-in version):

[image]

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ax.set_extent()](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.set_extent)

```
ax.set_extent([-150, -20, -90, 90])
```

Comment: It is good practice to include a `crs` when setting the extent so that the code will still work if the projection is changed, although in this example the outcome will be the same: `ax.set_extent([-150, -20, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())`